# Merge statement: Instead of DELETE, Enter record values in temporary table

Tags: t-sql, sql-server-2008

I have the following Merge statement I'm working with:

```
    MERGE dbo.UnitOfMeasure AS target
    USING (
        SELECT * FROM dbo.UnitOfMeasure
    ) AS src
    ON 
        target.UOMId = src.UOMId
    WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN           
        INSERT 
            (
                UOMId,
                UOM
            )  
        VALUES 
            (
                src.UOMId,
                src.UOM
            )
    WHEN NOT MATCHED BY SOURCE THEN 
        DELETE    <-- Do something other than delete here
    WHEN MATCHED THEN
        UPDATE SET 
            target.UOM = src.UOM;
```

Instead of actually deleting the records, I'd like to run a stored procedure for each record that was going to be deleted.  In essence, I can't simply delete these records.  Instead, I have  stored procedure that handles the deleting for me.  I just need to pass in the unique ID (UOMId) to the stored proc.

Anyone know of way to do this using the Merge statement?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I read the documentation correctly, it appears that the only options available to you from with the WHEN NOT MATCHED BY SOURCE clause are UPDATE and DELETE: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb510625.aspx.

Lame!  Executing a procedure would be endlessly useful here!  Even an INSERT would be sufficient for most scenarios...

Nevertheless, in your case, I would process these records in two steps.  1: Use MERGE with an UPDATE statement to flag the fields to be deleted.  2: Call your deletion code on the flagged fields.

Good luck!

Comment: This was going to be my next attempt.  Instead, I'm running the MERGE statement in a stored proc.  Before the MERGE command, I'm looping through the records in the target table that are not in the source table and deleting them.  It's not as pretty as a single command but it serves my purpose.  Thanks all.

Answer (score 0):

For the purpose of your question, `MERGE` is merely an explicit delete statement, just like `DELETE`. I suppose, you do not call `DELETE FROM table WHERE condition` in cases where you need a special delete processing which you have put into a stored procedure. Same should apply to `MERGE`. Of course, as a language feature, it might be nice to have an ability to call SPs from `MERGE`. But `MERGE` is a set statement, like `DELETE` or `UPDATE`, and the fact that it uses these keywords doesn't mean that it actually calls the respective statements for every row *individually*.

So, if I were you, I would forget about calling procedures from `MERGE`. Instead, as an option, I would consider moving your stored procedure's logic to a trigger (either `AFTER DELETE` or `INSTEAD OF DELETE`, depends on the situation). Of course, that would mean I'd have to run a complex logic *in a cursor **inside a trigger***, which most often is objectionable, but in some rare cases a necessary evil.